# how to rerender or call multiple times a screen react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

hi i have a simple panel that shows how many objects each section has, at now my code shows the correct number when it loads first, the problem is when the user insert a new object in one section, since the function doesnt load again it doesnt bring the new value

this is my api code, this is the one i need to clone or init each time the screen is displayed

```
const Panel = ({navigation}) => {

const [irregularities, setvirregularities] = useState();
const [approved, setvapproved] = useState();
const [sent, setvsent] = useState();
const [rejected, setvrejected] = useState();

useEffect(() => { 
  async  function Badge() { 
   const vCreationUser = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id');
   const { data } = await ForceApi.post(`/GetTotalRequestController.php`, {vCreationUser});
   console.log('UNO');
     setvirregularities(data.irregularities);
     setvapproved(data.request_approved);
     setvsent(data.sent);
     setvrejected(data.rejected);
   }
 Badge();
},[]);
```

this is where i show the info that i get from  the api

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}> 
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.linkContainer} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Solicitudes1')}>
                    <View style={irregularities == 0 ? styles.Badge2 : styles.Badge} ><Text style={styles.BadgeTXT}>{irregularities >= 100 ? '99+' : irregularities}</Text></View>
                    <View style={styles.buttonTextContainer}><Text style={styles.textPanel}>Irregularidades</Text></View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.linkContainer} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Solicitudes2')}>
                <View style={approved == 0 ? styles.Badge2 : styles.Badge} ><Text style={styles.BadgeTXT}>{approved >= 100 ? '99+' : approved}</Text></View>
                <View style={styles.buttonTextContainer}><Text style={styles.textPanel}>Cons. Apro.</Text></View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.linkContainer} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Solicitudes3')}>
                <View style={sent == 0 ? styles.Badge2 : styles.Badge} ><Text style={styles.BadgeTXT}>{sent >= 100 ? '99+' : sent}</Text></View>
                <View style={styles.buttonTextContainer}><Text style={styles.textPanel}>Enviadas</Text></View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.linkContainer} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Solicitudes4')}>
                <View style={rejected == 0 ? styles.Badge2 : styles.Badge} ><Text style={styles.BadgeTXT}>{rejected >= 100 ? '99+' : rejected}</Text></View>
                <View style={styles.buttonTextContainer}><Text style={styles.textPanel}>Rechazadas</Text></View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View>
);
```

TLDR: its something like notification on facebook, the problem is that i need to rerender the useEfect every time there is a change in the values

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I need more context of your code, but you can try using **the parameters array** of useEffect method.

`useEffect(() => {
}, [flagForNewObject])`

Above, every time that flagForNewObject value changes, the method run again.

Comment: i edited and showed the whole code, in fact yes the parameters array would be perfect, the problem is thhat all the values that can detect the change of value are inside the useEffect

Comment: Ok, but How does a change happen?

Comment: those are in others components, that arent communicated with this screen

Comment: inst there a way to just call itself everytime the user  visits or selects that tab?